# How Will I Test A MineSweepers Grid Paint Method?

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I'm trying to learn TDD by solving the problem of text based MineSweeper game. The last part in it was writing `fillGrid` method which paints the `Grid`

I ended up in:

```
public Grid fillGrid(Grid grid) {
        String[][] gridCells = grid.getGrid();

        fillBomb(grid);
        for(int i=0;i<gridCells.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<gridCells[0].length;j++){

                if(!constraints.checkBombsAndNumbersPresentAsRequrired(grid.getSurroundingValues(i,j)))
                {
                    if(gridCells[i][j] != "*") {
                        if(getBombCount(grid.getSurroundingValues(i, j)) != 0)
                            grid.setCells(i, j, "" + getBombCount(grid.getSurroundingValues(i, j)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        grid.prettyPrint( grid.getGrid() );

        return  null;
    }
```

In the above code I have tested both `fillBomb` and `checkBombsAndNumbersPresentAsRequried` separately. Now I'm sort of struck with how will I test the `fillGrid` in itself!

As I was trying to follow the TDD pattern I wrote `fillGrid` fail test cases like:

1. It should have only 4 bombs (sort of easy mode) -- made it fail
2. Check constraints whether the return `Grid` satisfies MineSweeper itself

The 2nd point where I'm struck. If I going to write a test cases for the 2nd point, it so likely that, I'm going to check the same logic in my test case too!

One thing I thought that I'm using `checkBombsAndNumbersPresentAsRequrired` which is clearly checks the formed data, but with this can we skip testing `fillGrid` in TDD, even though it does some crucial logic?

Am I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to learn TDD, the first thing to learn is to write a test before you write the code.  This will eliminate a lot of the problems with "how can I test this code" because you will already have the test.